# Post a link on Facebook wall og:image does not works

Tags: php, facebook, share

i just want to copy and paste my website links on users facebook walls , when share from http://www.tvguide.dk/nyheder/2011-10-15/TV2_satser:_Nu_med_spritnye_v%C3%A6rter_!/ share buttons it works and picks a correct og:image thumbnail ,

however when i copy paste the link on the wall the facebook picks the logo image. insted of og:image value

can you guys help me please

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to change that, unless you always upload a picture when you post on someones wall! The og:image is **only** used for the open graph which is used from like and share buttons, comments etc, but not in facebook itself.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on internationalization: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Your website is in Danish but you have used set locale as en_US. Also the title, type and URL properties are not being interpreted correctly by Facebook. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tvguide.dk%2Fnyheder%2F2011-10-15%2FTV2_satser%3A_Nu_med_spritnye_v%25C3%25A6rter_%21%2F

Make changes and check the progress at URL Debugger(Linter) given above. If everything fails try including the FBJS SDK and use fb:share-button. I had a similar problem once with WordPress which got solved using the JS SDK